# using C#, address split and only display suburbs name

Tags: c#

This code only display postcode (2477 and 2024)

**Input:**

Address:
Mr Kennedy,G
Unit 1 115 Oxford Avenue,
ALSTONVILLE 2477

Mr Johan Ed
100 Old South Head RD
Watson Bay 2024

**My efford:**

```
string suburbs = address.Split(' ').Last().ToString();
```

Could anyone please tell how do I  split(using C#) to only suburbs name.

**Expected Output:** 
ALSTONVILLE
Watson Bay

Comment: I think you can't achieve your requirement until you don't have fixed address format.
If you try to get second last word, than you will have only ALSTONVILLE and Bay

Comment: @Rob i formated your question to be easier to understand. feel free to roll back

Comment: As @Arvaan said, this isn't possible because the address input is not in a standard format. How are you getting this information? If it's coming from a form or another method you control can you update this to have each value in a different field?

Comment: IMO the only way to make this work is using something like google-maps (your own name-store will do too - if you have one) to check the suburbs against existing names

Comment: Why don't you get a list of suburbs correlates with postcode and then split out the postalcode and retrieves the name from that list?  would be a nicer solution to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your suburb is always in the 3rd/last line and the postal code is always digits only - this should work

```
string res = string.Concat( address.Split('\n').Last().Where( x => !char.IsDigit(x))).Trim();
```

**Input:**

Mr Johan Ed
100 Old South Head RD
Watson Bay 2024

**Result:**

Watson Bay

Comment: removed my downvote but it still feels hacky - what if there are letters in the zip-code or numbers in the city-name (yeah unlikely but I bet there are examples somewhere ...)

Comment: @Shaharyar  the question should provide a better definition of a address structure - in case of `Watson Bay 2024 a` the skipping approach would fail in this case too

Comment: Single suburbs name will works your code, only issuse is some suburb has two name for example Watson Bay, yours code will display only Watson

Comment: @fubo yes there must be a defined pattern, but as the test cases we can consider we have zip code at the end. PS: I am not the down voter :)

Answer (score 0):

My code doesn't look very short and professional so feel free to optimize, but it should return your expected output. If the structure of the address is ever the same it should work, also with digits in the city name.

```
    var firstsplit = address.Split('\n').Last();
    var secondsplit = firstsplit.Split(' ');
    var thridsplit = secondsplit.Where(x => x != secondsplit.Last());
    string erg = "";
    foreach (var split in thridsplit)
    {
        erg += split + " ";
    }
    erg = erg.TrimEnd(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is bit messy, but it works fine:

```
string suburb = string.Join(" ", address.Split('\n').Last()
    .Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Reverse().Skip(1)  //to remove zip code
    .Reverse().ToArray());   //to reset the order
```

It gets the last line, splits it and skip the last item then joins the array and return.

I had to use `Reverse` because `Skip` skips the first item.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the input has been taken from the Text File. Again I have put the same thing in text box as well if in case your program does so. Than Spilitting the addresses from Blank lines between the addresses and found the last line and removed the Digits if any.

```
string inp = File.ReadAllText("inp.txt");
string result1 = "";
TxtWebAdd.Text = inp;
var found = TxtWebAdd.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string fn in found)
{
    result1 = result1 + Regex.Replace(fn.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().ToString(), @"[\d-]", string.Empty) + "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 var address = "Mr Johan Ed 100\nOld South Head RD \nVishal Watson Bay 2024";
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"\b([a-zA-Z\s]*)\b");
 var last = address.Split('\n').Last();
 var address = reg.Match(last).ToString();
```